# List_view customized button

Tags: android

Hi guys I am new to android:- i want to know how to implement customized button in list view. can any one give a useful link. please guide me.

Comment: what kind of customization you want in android button i don't get it exact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an idea from this example
[Custom List View](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)